# A problem on mean value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1f(x)=0$. Prove
> there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $c^2f(c)=\int_0^c(x+x^2)f(x)dx$

Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $f$ attains max and min. Let $g(t)=\int_0^t(x+x^2)f(x)dx-t^2f(t)$. If $f$ attains max at $x=a$, $f(a)\ge0$ since the integral is 0. So $g(a)\le\int_0^a(x+x^2)f(a)dx-a^2f(a)=(a^2/2+a^3/3-a^2)f(a)\le0$. Similarly if $f$ attains min at $x=b$ so that $f(b)\le0$, then $g(b)\ge\int_0^b(x+x^2)f(b)dx-b^2f(b)=(b^2/2+b^3/3-b^2)f(b)\ge0$. Therefore by intermediate value thm there exists $c\in[\min(a,b),\max(a,b)]$ such that $g(c)=0$. Now what if max or min fall on the endpoint and $g(a)$ or $g(b)$ equal to $0$?

Comment: (Removed my previous useless comment) There is a solution by Babylon5 [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h524061p2961300) but it's IMO too long winded and unclear. Someone can help clear it up in an answer below.

Comment: Note that the IVT tells you that $c$ is in an open interval (not a closed interval as you wrote in your post ) This means you'll have to to treat the case $a = b$ separately since the interval in which $c$ lies would be empty in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> Now what if max or min fall on the endpoint and $g(a)$ or $g(b)$ equal to $0$ ?

There are several scenarios. Either $\{a,b \} = \{0,1\}$ or only one of $a$ and $b$ is on the edge of the interval with the other point equal to some $c$ in $(0,1)$.

We start with the case $a = 0$ and $b \in (0,1)$. Clearly $g(a) = 0$ and we can suppose WLOG that $g(b) \neq 0$. That is, $g(b)> 0$.

We can also suppose that $f(0) > 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$ would imply that $f = 0$.

By the maximality of $f$ at $a = 0$ it follows that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that
$$ f(t) \leq f(0)$$
for all $t \in (0,\epsilon)$
Note that if $f(t) = f(0)$ then $f$ also has a maximum at $t$ so instead of taking $a = 0$ we could have chosen $a = t \in (0,1)$ and we therefore bring ourselves to a case we've already solved. This means that we can suppose that
$$ f(t) < f(0) \qquad \forall x \in (0,\epsilon).$$

It follows that

$$ g(t) = \int_0^t (x^2 + x) f(x) dx - t^2f(t) < (t^3/3 + t^2/2)f(0) - t^2 f(0) = (t^3/3+t^2/2-t^2)f(0)$$

since the polynomial $(t^3/3+t^2/2-t^2)$ is strictly negative on $(0,1)$ and $f(0) > 0$  We deduce that

$$ g(t) < 0$$

It follows by IVF that $g$ has a zero in $(t,b)$ where $t \in (0,\epsilon).$

---

For the case $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ I suggest you do the same and also look at the sign of $g(1 - t')$ where $t'$ is small and show that it is strictly positive.

---

The proofs for the case $b = 0, a \in (0,1]$ should follow from similar arguments.